# Use Of Return In Programming

Tags: java

I am confused with the return keyword. I know of these usages:

A. When we have to print something

```
System.out.println(functionname());
```

B. When we have to copy the output of the function to something

```
int c=function(3);
```

Is there is any other use for it?

---

I'm having another question, regarding this task:

> Create a class person having two instance fields- height and weight.
>   Include one method update_fields which accepts object of the same
>   class and returns the object of the class after doubling the height
>   and weight of the passed object.

In the update field method why do we need to pass the object as the argument when the method will be called by `objectname.methodname();`
?
And what is the use of `return` after doubling the values?

```
class Person
{
    int ht;
    int wt;
    Person update_fields(Person p1)
    {

        p1.ht*=2;
        p1.wt*=2;
        return p1 ;
    }
}
```

I fell like the question should have been like to just double the values without taking the argument and returning anything.

```
 void update_fields()
        {

            p1.ht*=2;
            p1.wt*=2;

        }
```

Comment: Your first code fragment is indeed a bit "bad design" I would say. A better way should be to make the method `static`. Returning the `Person` however can be interesting to do *chaining*.

Answer (score 0):

In java you create a network of interacting pieces of code. The most relevant technique to let one method pass a value to another is to use `return`. It lets one method pass a result of a computation or variable access to the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to programming.

Second, "Return" is the keyword that tells a method to report back some sort of value.  It can only return 1 value, but that value can be an object, like a class or an array.

Third, the reason you pass the Person class into the method is a question of scope.  Yes, each Person has a height and a weight, but each Person has a *different* height and weight.  What the method does is double the height and weight of *that* Person, not ALL Persons.  If you want ALL Persons to share a height and weight, you would have to make the fields static.  Then if you changed the value of height or weight tin ANY Person, they would all change.

Answer (score 0):

When a method is called, the method executes statements and then it might or might not return a value.

If the method's return type is specified as `void`, then it does not return a value. If it is anything else than `void` (for example, `int` or `Person` or `String` or any other type), then the method must return a value, and it must use the `return` keyword to return that value.

In the place where the method is called, you can indeed store the result in a variable, like in the example you gave:

```
// Store whatever function(3) returns into the variable c
int c = function(3);
```

Or you can immediately pass the return value to another method, as you are doing in your first example:

```
// Pass whatever functionname() returns to the method println()
// of the System.out object
System.out.println(functionname());

// This is the same as storing the value first:
Object result = functionname();
System.out.println(result);
```

Setter methods such as `update_fields` in your example should not normally get the object passed to them in which you want to set the values. Just set the values on the current object. Such methods normally also do not return an object.

```
class Person
{
    int ht;
    int wt;

    void update_fields()
    {
        ht *= 2;
        wt *= 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> now in the update field method why do we need to pass the object as
>   the argument when the method will be called by
>   objectname.methodname(); ??

I agree with you here, there wouldn't be a need to pass in a reference to a person object to the `update_fields` method considering that you can modify the `person` fields of `ht` and `wt` through the public fields (package bound).

```
class Person
{
    int ht;
    int wt;
    Person update_fields(Person p1)
    {

        p1.ht*=2;
        p1.wt*=2;
        return p1 ;
    }
}
```

---

> what is the use of return after doubling the values?

`return` is simple, as the name states it's used to `return` data, in your case it's used to `return` the reference to the `person` object after its state has been mutated/changed.

---

> I fell like the question should have been like to just double the
>   values without taking the argument and returning anything.

you're looking for something like below:

**example:**

```
class Person
{
    private int ht;
    private int wt;

    void update_fields(){
       ht *= 2;
       wt *= 2;
   }
}
```

the approach above considers complete encapsulation and whenever it's invoked the corresponding object states ( `ht` & `wt`) will be mutated/changed.

**Conclusion**

> Create a class person having two instance fields- height and weight.
>   Include one method update_fields which accepts object of the same
>   class and returns the object of the class after doubling the height
>   and weight of the passed object.

Had the fields been declared as `private` in the `person` class like below:

```
class Person
{
    private int ht;
    private int wt;
    Person update_fields(Person p1)
    {

        p1.ht*=2;
        p1.wt*=2;
        return p1 ;
    }
}
```

then it would make sense to pass in a `person` object to the method as that would be the only way to mutate/change its state when you create an object of it. This is of course excluding `getters` and `setters` that is. Having said that, it's an overhead to pass objects around just for that purpose, would be easier to create `getters` and `setters` for it.

Finally, considering that it's a task you're given then I would simply advise to do it as it says.

Comment: even if the fields are pvt , then again without passing the object we can double up the things by using a public method ?

Comment: @MridulMittal yep, that's possible, see my second example from the top of my post. Also, if the post has solved your solution don't forget to mark as accepted. :).

Answer (score 0):

Printing and assignment to variables (what you called "*copy*") are two uses for a `return` value. You can also use the returned value as input to another method call:

```
int x = calculator.add(3,calculator.add(4,5));
```

It helps to think about objects as machines that do something useful, and methods as the way you interact with the machine. Sometimes when you do something to a machine, you don't want to see a result (or you're satisfied with a *side-effect*, for example it prints something to the screen, saves something to a file, etc).

More of the time, when you do something to the machine you want something back to say what happened -- when I put a coin in a machine, I want a can of drink in return. When I enter `3 + 3 =` into a calculator, I want it to tell me `6`.

`return` has two uses:

1. To leave a method before its closing `}`
2. To tell the method what value to supply the caller

If a method's return type is `void`, then only the first use applies:

```
 public void printBiggerNumbers(int num) {
      if(num < 10) {
           return;
      }
      System.out.println(num);
 }
```

`return` is optional when the return type is `void`.

If a method's return type is anything but `void` then all possible paths through the method **must** end in a `return`, so that something of the right type is returned.

```
 public int sumBiggerNumbers(int x, int y) {
      if(x > 10 && y > 10) {
           return x + y;
      }
 }
```

... will not compile, because it's possible to reach the final `}` without hitting `return`. The program won't know what to do, so it doesn't make sense.

(There is an alternative -- instead of **returning**, a method can **throw an exception**, but you will learn about this another day)

Your example isn't something many programmers would do, because as you've noticed, it doesn't make a lot of sense. You would be more likely to make this a `void` method that operates on `this`:

```
class Person {
    int ht;
    int wt;

    void updateFields()
    {
        this.ht *= 2;
        this.wt *= 2;
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.ht = 20;
p.wt = 10;
p.updateFields();
System.out.println("" + p.ht + " " + p.wt);
```

The common pattern of **getters and setters** demonstrates very clearly:

- methods that return `void`, have a parameter, and change the state of an object
- methods that return something, have no parameter, and don't change the state of an object

  ```
  class Person {
       private int ht;
       private int wt;

       public void setHt(int ht)
       {
           this.ht = ht;
       }

       public int getHt() {
           return ht;
       }
   }
   ...

   Person p = new Person();
   p.setHt(6);
   System.out.println("Height: " + p.getHt);
  ```

  There is a design pattern that does something similar to what you have stumbled on, that is, to work on an object and return it, and that is **fluent APIs**. This is a fairly advanced topic for an absolute beginner like you, so feel free to skip it for now, but:

  ```
  public class Person {
      private int ht;
      private int wt;

      public Person withHt(int ht) {
          this.ht = ht;
          return this;
      }

      public Person withWt(int wt) {
          this.wt = wt;
          return this;
      }
  }
  ```

... allows us to call it like:

```
Person p = new Person().withHt(6).withWt(3);
```

I don't recommend that you do exactly this, but it's a simplified version of the **Builder Pattern** which is very useful in some circumstances.